# Using dynamic values in AS portion of an SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a query (and a long, nasty bugger it is) to return dynamically updating values from an SAP system. I've got everything figured out but how to make the column headers what I want. They need to be the name of the previous 11 months and this month (or the 3 letter abbreviation).

Currently, I just have

```
SELECT ... AS [OCT]
```

for this month, but in two days it's going to be different, and I'd like to have the query auto-update the column headers each time it is run.

I figured out that I can use the variables I have declared to use in my functions to get the name three letter name of the month:

```
DECLARE @last_month DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 0, 0)
SELECT CONVERT(char(3), @last_month);
```

to return the selected month. How do I get this to be usable in the "AS" field?

Here is what I currently have:

```
DECLARE @last_two_months DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
DECLARE @last_month DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 0, 0)
SELECT (a whole mess of things that somehow work) AS [SEPT],
Table.CurrentTotal AS [OCT];
```

I'd like to replace [OCT] with something that will return OCT as the column header for the next two days and then return NOV for the next month, and similarly changing [SEPT] to something that will return SEP for the next two days, then return OCT for the next month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dynamic Query`

```
DECLARE @last_month DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 0, 0),
        @alias char(3),
        @sql nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT @alias= CONVERT(char(3), @last_month);

set @sql = 'SELECT ... as ['+@alias+']..'

--Print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Use the `Print` Statement to debug the dynamic query

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're saying to do. (I HATE ENTER TO SAVE COMMENT). Let me add some more info to the question.

Comment: Alternatively, is there any way to return the column name as a variable? If there is, then I can make it work.